# Why did Qi'ra make the decision she did in the end?

Tags: star-wars, solo-a-star-wars-story

At the end of *Solo: A Star Wars Story*, we see

> Qi'ra calls up Crimson Dawn, which turns out to be an alias for Darth Maul and/or his organization. She proceeds to inform him of the events that transpired, albeit leaving out some details like letting Han/Chewie go with the Coaxium, instead just stating it was gone. Maul then tells her to come to join him, of which she obliges.

My understanding of the scene was that she did it to

> protect Han so they wouldn't be hunted down together by Crimson Dawn.

But others I watched it with seemed to take it as betrayal, showing that she couldn't be trusted.

Do we know what her allegiances were in the end, and why she made the decision she did?

Comment: I thought the same thing you did. She lied to protect Han and Chewie, although her real motivations would fall under "future works" in case there's a sequel, or it's followed up in the Obi-Wan or Boba Fett movies. The cast was signed for 3 movies, after all...

Comment: Or, acquiring a powerful ally rather than a powerful enemy seemed a good bargain. Anyhow, it's all speculation.

Answer (score 3):

Qi'ra said that Han had no idea about what she had done for Crimson Dawn which even Dryden Vos pretty much said the same thing about what she had done. Apparently the things she had done made it hard to be with a good guy like Han. If we go by what Nest said there's a pretty good chance that Qi'ra was part of the assault on the people where they dropped off the coaxium. We don't know what she had done but  I'd say she went as far as taking innocent lives for Crimson Dawn.